# Is there a word or phrase for borders being respected

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, politics

Is there a word or phrase that means a "condition in which the borders of each nation are respected by all other nations"?

Comment: Tibet.  No, wait.

Comment: "Treaty of Algeron."

Comment: ... so for all we know, it actually starts with a V. This is too localized and is better taken to our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage), for which you have sufficient reputation. The main site is not really meant as a free crossword-solving service. Plus you can, and are arguably supposed to, wait for the solution to be published, just like everyone else. As an added bonus, the solution will have the one true answer, as opposed to a bunch of guesses, all equally correct, from random people off the Internet.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about solving a cross-word puzzle.

Comment: The question has been fixed to reflect your suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Territorial integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Territorial_integrity)** is the principle under international law that nation-states should not attempt to promote secessionist movements or to promote border changes in other nation-states.